# Understanding Jmeter load testing tool

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

As am working in a testing industry, I need to learn bit more about JMETER load testing tool, Please provide details of JMETER load testing tool, how many users(threads), ramp up period, need to define while doing load testing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the documentation link below for your reference:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html